# Steps in updating single field for multiple (selected) lists items

Tags: 2010, jquery, custom-actions, approval-process, custom-action

I am very new in SharePoint and wanted to seek some help.  I have created a simple SP list that has a simple approval process. It is working fine.

However, I was task to enhance it by allowing the approval of multiple/selected list items which I have no idea how to proceed.

[image]

Basically, it's just to select the lists items and have a custom action/button that when click, it will just update and set the value of the field "Status" from "Submitted for Approval" to "APPROVED".

We are using SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint Designer 2010.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom action for such requirements. In below blog you can find the detailed explanation to approve/reject multiple list items:

[SharePoint 2010: Approve/Reject Multiple Items](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2011/05/sharepoint-2010-approvereject-multiple.html).

I found another similar thread which is updated solution for above code reference:

[Updated – Approve or Reject multiple items in a SharePoint 2010 list](https://ianankers.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/updated-approve-or-reject-multiple-items-in-a-sharepoint-2010-list-5/).